Saving Resized Animated GIF Matching Canvas Output
I am working on an exercise that allows users to upload an image, resize it, and download the resized image. The functionality works well for static images (JPEG, PNG), but I am encountering issues with saving resized animated GIFs.
When a user uploads an animated GIF, the image is composited and displayed correctly, but attempting to save the canvas output just results in saving the original uploaded gif.
Code below:
https://jsfiddle.net/Aloe10211/uxzbwcaj/1/
let originalImage = null;
let originalImageType = '';

document.getElementById('upload').addEventListener('change', function(event) {
    const file = event.target.files[0];
    if (!file) return;

    originalImageType = file.type;

    if (file.type === 'image/gif') {
        const reader = new FileReader();
        reader.onload = function(e) {
            originalImage = e.target.result;
            document.getElementById('buttons').style.display = 'none';
            processGIF(originalImage);
        };
        reader.readAsDataURL(file);
    } else {
        const reader = new FileReader();
        reader.onload = function(e) {
            originalImage = e.target.result;
            document.getElementById('buttons').style.display = 'block';
        };
        reader.readAsDataURL(file);
    }
});

document.getElementById('smol50').addEventListener('click', function() {
    resizeImage(0.5);
});

document.getElementById('smol75').addEventListener('click', function() {
    resizeImage(0.25);
});

document.getElementById('smol90').addEventListener('click', function() {
    resizeImage(0.1);
});

function resizeImage(scale) {
    processImage(originalImage, scale);
}

function processImage(dataUrl, scale) {
    const img = new Image();
    img.onload = function() {
        const canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
        const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
        const width = img.width * scale;
        const height = img.height * scale;

        canvas.width = width;
        canvas.height = height;

        ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0, width, height);

        const resizedImage = canvas.toDataURL('image/png');

        document.getElementById('output').src = resizedImage;
        document.getElementById('output-container').style.display = 'block';

        const downloadLink = document.getElementById('download');
        downloadLink.href = resizedImage;
        downloadLink.download = 'resized_image.png';
        downloadLink.style.display = 'block';
        downloadLink.innerText = 'Download Resized Image';
    }
    img.src = dataUrl;
}

function processGIF(dataUrl) {
    document.getElementById('output').src = dataUrl;
    document.getElementById('output').style.width = '100px';
    document.getElementById('output').style.height = 'auto';
    document.getElementById('output-container').style.display = 'block';

    const downloadLink = document.getElementById('download');
    downloadLink.href = dataUrl;
    downloadLink.download = 'resized_image.gif';
    downloadLink.style.display = 'block';
    downloadLink.innerText = 'Download Resized GIF';
}



The composited animated GIF uploads and displays correctly.
When resized, the GIF saves as the original gif file with no modification.

Expected:

The resized and composited GIF should be downloadable as an animated GIF matching the canvas output.


Are you open to use any third party script for this there gif script that do that work in javascript

Totally! Open to anything really, just trying to understand better.

Your code does not resize the .gif, it only displays it smaller. Not the same thing. If you ran the .gif through the same code as you do .jpg and .png files, then it would get resized. The problem however, with resizing a .gif by drawing it to the canvas, is that you only draw one frame to the canvas and thus end up with a static .png version of the .gif.

@RayWallace Ahh yes that makes sense, thank you! Do you know of an efficient way to break the gif into frames for resizing and then reassembly?

gif.js library is used for this kind of operations
